# Integrate node-soap in sails.js

Tags: node.js, express, soap, sails.js, node-soap

I have a running [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) application. It mostly uses **models** and its corresponding **controllers** with REST blueprint actions.

In addition, I need to expose a SOAP endpoint and I ended up using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap).

All the official examples are coded with [express](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soaplistenserver-path-services-wsdl---create-a-new-soap-server-that-listens-on-path-and-provides-services).

Has anyone known a way to integrate it?

Comment: I would not recommend to have soap-server integrated in sails. Just make them two separate projects.

Comment: @zabware I was considering an additional express server. My concern is that waterline models are almost the same. So, maybe running both applications and deriving the request internally.